# What to do with negative rho values in hough transform?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Here is my code for creating the `hough accumulator` for lines in image :

```
void hough_lines_acc(cv::Mat img_a_edges, std::vector<std::vector<int> > &hough_acc) {
  for (size_t r = 0; r < img_a_edges.rows; r++) {
    for (size_t c = 0; c < img_a_edges.cols; c++) {
      int theta = static_cast<int> (std::atan2(r, c) * 180 / M_PI);
      int rho = static_cast<int> ((c * cos(theta)) + (r * sin(theta)));
      if (theta < -90) theta = -90;
      if (theta > 89) theta = 89;

      ++hough_acc[abs(rho)][theta];
    }
  }

  cv::Mat img_mat(hough_acc.size(), hough_acc[0].size(), CV_8U);

  std::cout << hough_acc.size() << "  " << hough_acc[0].size() << std::endl;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < hough_acc.size(); i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < hough_acc[0].size(); j++) {
      img_mat.at<int> (i,j) = hough_acc[i][j];
    }
  }

  imwrite("../output/ps1-­2-­b-­1.png", img_mat);
}
```

`theta` varies from `-90 to 89`. I am getting negative rho values. Right now I am just replacing the negative who with a positive one but am not getting a correct answer. What do I do to the negative rho? Please explain the answer.

theta = arctan (y / x)
rho = x * cos(theta) + y * sin(theta)

Edited code :

```
bool hough_lines_acc(cv::Mat img_a_edges, std::vector<std::vector<int> > &hough_acc,\
   std::vector<double> thetas, std::vector<double> rhos, int rho_resolution, int theta_resolution) {
  int img_w = img_a_edges.cols;
  int img_h = img_a_edges.rows;

  int max_votes = 0;
  int min_votes = INT_MAX;

  for (size_t r = 0; r < img_h; r++) {
    for (size_t c = 0; c < img_w; c++) {
      if(img_a_edges.at<int>(r, c) == 255) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < thetas.size(); i++) {
          thetas[i] = (thetas[i] * M_PI / 180);
          double rho = ( (c * cos(thetas[i])) + (r * sin(thetas[i])) );
          int buff = ++hough_acc[static_cast<int>(abs(rho))][static_cast<int>(i)];

          if (buff > max_votes) {
            max_votes = buff;
          }
          if (buff < min_votes) {
            min_votes = buff;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  double div = static_cast<double>(max_votes) / 255;
  int threshold = 10;
  int possible_edge = round(static_cast<double>(max_votes) / div) - threshold;

  props({
    {"max votes", max_votes},
    {"min votes", min_votes},
    {"scale", div}
  });
  // needed for scaling intensity for contrast
  // not sure if I am doing it correctly
  for (size_t r = 0; r < hough_acc.size(); r++) {
    for (size_t c = 0; c < hough_acc[0].size(); c++) {
      double val = hough_acc[r][c] / div;
      if (val < 0) {
        val = 0;
      }

      hough_acc[r][c] = static_cast<int>(val);
    }
  }


  cv::Mat img_mat = cv::Mat(hough_acc.size(), hough_acc[0].size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));

  for (size_t i = 0; i < hough_acc.size(); i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < hough_acc[0].size(); j++) {
      img_mat.at<uint8_t> (i,j) = static_cast<uint8_t>(hough_acc[i][j]);
    }
  }

  imwrite("../output/ps1-­2-­b-­1.png", img_mat);
  return true;
}
```

Still not correct output. What is the error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

atan2 of two positive numbers... should not be giving you negative angles, it should only be giving you a range of 0-90

also for the hough transform, I think you want everything relative to one point (ie 0,0 in this case).  I think for that you would actually want to make theta=90-atan2(r,c)

Admittedly though, I am a bit confused as I thought you had to encode line direction, rather than just "edge pt".  ie I thought at each edge point you had to provide a discrete array of guessed line trajectories and calculate rho and theta for each one and throw all of those into your accumulator.  As is... I am not sure what you are calculating.

Comment: I don't think I really understand the algo really well :/ In the course the prof said `d =  x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta)` and assignment says `rho =  x * cos(theta) + y * sin(theta)`. What's the difference? By the language it seems d and rho are same as prof is mapping the hough acc as H[d, theta].

Comment: Also, I am meant to include an option in the algo where theta is allowed values b/w -90 and 89. We are calculating theta. How do I allow this? This is what it says : `with one optional parameter specified (θ = integers ­90  to 89 , i.e. 180  values
including 0 )`.

Comment: OH!  I think I understand!  You do not want to calculate theta from anything, that is going to be your discrete list that I mentioned.  Make an array of values between -90 and 90 (by say 30 degree increments).  Then for each edge point in the array, calculate rho for each theta and add each one into your accumulator.
-------
To understand the algo a little better (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform): just imagine that at every point you are generating a star pattern of lines (guesses).  Points that are linearly related should add to the same guess, creating your peaks!

Comment: And your function parameters would specify probably the range of guesses (-90 to 90) or more or less and or the increment steps (30 degrees).  This would allow for increasing resolution in your rho theta space.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now.

Comment: Can you please also tell what is `d` and how is it similar/different to `rho`?

Comment: d and rho are the same thing.  Basically, a rho-theta combination is a unique possible line in the image.  So if you picture some line in an image, theta is going to be the angle between that line and the x axis (angle on top left at intersection).  Now the problem is there are lots of possible lines with that same angle, so rho is the perpendicular distance from that line to the origin (ie you can think of it as the shortest distance from that line to the origin).  With those two values, the line descriptor is now unique

Comment: You should also consider that one of the axis for images are on the opposite direction the usual axis are. Usually both x and y diverge from the center center of the coordinate system, but in images 0,0 is not the center, but the upper left corner.